# How to make coffee candy to eat later?

Tags: sugar, ground-coffee

When I drink coffee with my stomach not very full, I usually don't feel very well later on. Because of this, I tried to start eating the coffee instead!

I've been trying to make some kind of coffee candy with just sugar and coffee, sometimes I try adding some oil, but it's not getting in the way I want it too.

I'm using raw grounds into it (When I'm lazy I just eat the grounds with sugar ^^'), and I wanted it to become more solid, kinda like chocolate, but from coffee.

What I'm doing for now is:

Melting sugar in low heat with very little water, mixing the grounds in the molten sugar, then let it cook for some time while mixing it, and then I take it out from the fire into a plastic container.

I tried mixing the sugar and the coffee before melting too, and I've tried mixing some oil on it before and after melting the sugar.

Do anyone know any recipe for this, preferably with the raw grounds?
(I made some research, coffee grounds have lots of anti-oxidants fibers and other good things, so I want to keep using it xD)

Comment: Did you tried any of these? [candy](http://blog.timesunion.com/aprofessorswife/hard-tack-candy-recipe/3708/) - [toffee](https://smittenkitchen.com/2009/12/coffee-toffee/)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Coffee! It looks like you've made a good start in trying to produce an edible coffee product. Could you describe the issue with your current results? This way we may be better able to suggest alterations to your recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! My current "recipe" results in a "candy" not very hard, and it's like the sugar isn't melting very well, it's full of sugar cristals in it. I'm using cristalized sugar, but I think that one of the problems is that I'm making batches so small that it's overheating too fast, when I try just to melt the sugar without water it quickly start to burn instead of melting! D=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a great idea to make your own coffee candy. I've had both chocolate covered espresso beans as well as hard coffee candy from some local stores around my area. I prefer the hard candy because of the fact that I eat the former option way to quickly.

Here's a great resource on how to make both a soft chewy coffee candy as well as a hard one: [How to make coffee candy](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-make-coffee-candy/)

Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: Maybe this recipe is also of interest: https://epcur.com/recipes/caramel-cream-candy-with-coffee/

Answer (score 3):

I was at a new restaurant in my area the other day, and they had this ingenious little snack: **Chocolate-covered coffee beans.** The beans are left as they would be just prior to grinding them into grounds, and covered in a layer of chocolate, with a nice crunch to them. It's really as simple as it sounds.

I've been working on finding them in local supermarkets. Gourmet and specialty grocers such as Trader Joe's or Whole Foods might have them; I'm not sure.

Comment: In fact, here's just that on Amazon (though they're notably cheaper in stores): [link](https://www.amazon.com/Trader-Joes-Chocolate-Covered-Espresso/dp/B009RS7VIK)

Comment: I actually saw some time ago a coffee candy  made with cocoa butter, just like chocolate, but with coffee instead of cocoa. But it was kinda pricey and not diy. xD

Comment: Well this is both fairly inexpensive and possible to DIY! Good luck~

Comment: This is very common in Turkey, I know a coffee store named kahvedunyasi is selling packaged forms of them (white, milk or bitter chocolate, etc). I've checked now and they've an online store also stores in England and Romania, too.  In case someone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options that are primarily coffee and sugar: hard coffee candy or coffee toffee.

Here are links to recipients for both

[hard candy](https://artzcool.net/tag/homemade-hard-candies/)

[toffee](http://www.ehow.com/how_12342931_addictive-homemade-coffee-caramels-recipe.html?utm_content=freestyle&utm_medium=referral&crlt.pid=camp.cP2XbNcgRn6H&crlt.pid=camp.r14vsHdxWQp4&utm_source=pinterest.com&utm_campaign=fanpage)

Enjoy!